# Is it acceptable to take a day off during crunch time when it seemingly doesn't matter to my boss?

Tags: work-life-balance, vacation, time-off, deadlines

There is a high priority project I am working on that needs to be completed in 2 weeks.

Chances are that I will complete it, but the timing is tight.

I wanted to take a day off in the next few days but thought it may be best not to as this may stall the project for a day.

Boss however said he didn't particularity care if I did it not.  He is quite aware of the project but didn't seem to be concerned about whether I take the day off or not.

With that do I take the day off anyway or do I seek other arrangements?

Comment: If you take a day off and the project burns, what is the likelihood you can be blamed (rightly or wrongly)... Because if that happens and it is possible to blame you then that is what will happen... Taking time off in the final crunch period of a project should not be done lightly, unless your support is immaterial to the success of the project.

Comment: Maybe he just expects you to work extra on the days you are in the office, to hit the deadline? In which case you're wasting your day off.

Comment: The whole question seems awfully vague... Wether you should or shouldn't depends on the exact circumtances of your reason to take the day of, as well the situation of the project, consequences of it being late, the other people working on the project... There's nothing in the question which would allow clear "yes" or "no" answer.

Comment: Many things to consider here. If your boss has given you autonomy and you have proved in the past that you get shit done then he may not be concerned. Or perhaps he's nice and wants to give employees as much time off as they need, but will definitely get pissed if you take advantage of it. If it were me in my situation I would not take the day off because if some issue comes up with the project then someone might bring up the fact that you took time off and weren't devoted to the timeline.

Answer (score 15):

If your boss said he doesn't care if you take a day off, I would not take that to mean he doesn't care if the project slips. I take that to mean he trusts you to know if you can afford to take a day off.

Taking the day or not is a personal judgement call, but I would be hesitant unless I really needed to do it. Unexpected things come up that can seriously delay your project at the worst time. My personal recommendation - if you can wait, take the vacation day when the project is complete. It will be a nice reward for getting something done. If you have an appointment you really can't delay, then your boss has certainly given you the all clear to take a day off. Just know that there might be unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 3):

If it's okay with your superiors then do it. That's what holidays are for...

If anything you might be able to work better after having relaxed in a large crunch time.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is that unless you *need* to take a day off, put your head down and grind through to the project's completion, then take your day off. You won't have the project hanging over your vacation day, and your vacation day will not be pointed to as an irresponsible cause of failure. I'm not saying that it *is* irresponsible, just that it can be thrown in your face if something goes wrong.

At my job, there is the expectation that, if at all possible, time off be planned several weeks in advance (except in case of illness or emergency) so that projects can be planned accordingly.

I don't think it's *bad* if you take the day off, but I don't think it adds to your reputation either. If you have to, then do it. If you don't, then wait, because it can really only hurt your image, whereas waiting will enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

If the day off is for something important to you that can't or shouldn't be postponed, then I would take it off.

If it's just a day off for no particular reason, or for something easily postponed, then I would probably postpone it.